# Sample example on asp.net mvc design pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Am very new to MVC design pattern.Can u explain me a simple code in asp.net using MVC design pattern.

Comment: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 2):

IN the future, before posting here your first call should be http://www.asp.net/mvc
 - which includes a link to  [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28VS.98%29.aspx) and a [code walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Happy coding (and good luck)